# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: on ubuntu core after running snap of web app

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I have created a python based web server and made a snap of it and upload stable version on snap store. When i download and run that server on Ubuntu core machine, it throws the following error:

```
 File "/snap/alphawebserver/14/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 628, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/snap/alphawebserver/14/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 687, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/snap/alphawebserver/14/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/snap/alphawebserver/14/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 54, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/snap/alphawebserver/14/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cherryserver.py", line 25, in index
    with open(storagedirectory+'adminlogin.json', 'w') as outfile:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/alphaict/snap/alphawebserver/adminlogin.json'
```

could you please tell me how to fix it that error?

is it an Ubuntu core issue or a snap issue?

One more hint, When i run web server in `devmode` it works fine.

Thanks